# In how many ways can the 10 vacant positions be filled?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 10 vacant positions in the central cabinet of ministers. There is a total of 350 MPs in the ruling party. A cabinet post can be given to any of these MPs and an MP can take more than one cabinet position. In how many ways can the 10 vacant positions be filled?

Comment: If each position is unique, then apply rule of product.  Choose who takes the first position.  Choose who takes the second position.  Continue and multiply to conclude.  If positions are not considered unique for whatever reason... but number of positions taken by a particular minister still matters, then apply "stars-and-bars."

Comment: This, along with its various rewordings, is a standard "balls-in-bins" problem type and is covered by the [twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way), a standard collection of problem types and answers that should be known to every beginning student of combinatorics.

Answer (score 1):

Since each post has 350 possibilities the answer is $350^{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

If each MP can take on several positions, argue that the first position can be filled in $350$ ways, the second position can be filled in $350$ ways (this includes the MP taking the first post), and so on. In all, $350^{10}$.

If each MP can occupy just one position, the first one can be filled in $350$ ways, which leaves $350 - 1$ for the second, up to $350 - 9$ for the last. In all, $350 \cdot 349 \cdot \dotsm \cdot 341 = 350^{\underline{10}}$. This last product is called a *falling power*, the notation I use is the one advocated by Knuth. There are others. You could also write it as $350! / 340!$.